# Gets value from combobox in wpf binding by entity framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, combobox

I bind my combobox from entityframework and when I try to get value from my combobox by selecting value it gives back text like this {NameOfCompany = Name } How can i get only the value Name?

Thats the code in xaml

```
 <ComboBox  SelectionChanged="ComboFirma_SelectionChanged" Name="ComboFirma"  Margin="109,10,10,0" Height="28" VerticalAlignment="Top">
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <TextBlock Name="txbCombo" Text="{Binding NameOfCompany}"></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
 </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

And I bind it like this.

```
var query2 = from f in model.Firmas
                     select new
                     {
                         f.NameOfCompany
                     };
ComboFirma.ItemsSource = query2.ToList();
```

I tried something like this to gets the selected value but always i get an exception.

```
var str = (TextBox)ComboFirma.Template.FindName("txbCombo", ComboFirma);
        lblCompanyNameShow.Content = str.SelectedText;
```

Answer (score 1):

`ComboBox.SelectedItem` will be of a item type. So normally you would need to cast `SelectedItem` to type of item in your collection. Now, because, in your case it's anonymous type, it's more difficult I think easiest way to get `NameOfCompany` is to use `dynamic`

```
dynamic selectedItem = ComboFirma.SelectedItem;
var name = selectedItem.NameOfCompany;
```

or you can use `SelectedValue`/`SelectedValuePath`

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboFirma" ... SelectedValuePath="NameOfCompany">
```

and in code

```
var name = (string)ComboFirma.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: There is an error" The name "txbCombo" does not exist in current context"

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
TextBlock tb1 = (TextBlock)ComboFirma.SelectedItem;
lblCompanyNameShow.Content = str.SelectedText;
```

Comment: it throws an exceptions also